# Kubespray: send request failed caused by: Post https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm trying to install Kubernetes with Kubespray using AWS a cloud provider. The installation fails with

`FAILED - RETRYING: Master | wait for the apiserver to be running`

When I check the logs of the kubelet docker container on the master I see

```
Flag --enable-cri has been deprecated, The non-CRI implementation will be deprecated and removed in a future version.
I0824 16:30:03.413509   13279 feature_gate.go:144] feature gates: map[Accelerators:true]
I0824 16:30:03.413727   13279 aws.go:762] Building AWS cloudprovider
I0824 16:30:03.413878   13279 aws.go:725] Zone not specified in configuration file; querying AWS metadata service
Error: failed to run Kubelet: could not init cloud provider "aws": error finding instance i-0cb81504d85c14b90: error listing AWS instances: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 54.239.28.168:443: i/o timeout
Error: failed to run Kubelet: could not init cloud provider "aws": error finding instance i-0cb81504d85c14b90: error listing AWS instances: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 54.239.28.168:443: i/o timeout
Flag --enable-cri has been deprecated, The non-CRI implementation will be deprecated and removed in a future version.
I0824 16:32:04.169558   13517 feature_gate.go:144] feature gates: map[Accelerators:true]
I0824 16:32:04.169808   13517 aws.go:762] Building AWS cloudprovider
I0824 16:32:04.169852   13517 aws.go:725] Zone not specified in configuration file; querying AWS metadata service
```

I'm positive this is a firewall issue. I have an IAM role with the proper permissions. When I set the https_proxy variable I am able to

```
curl https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

When the proxy variable is not set the curl fails. I tried setting the https_proxy variable inside the hyperkube container. However this causes a cert error when the apiserver tries to handshake with the etcd nodes.

Is there a way to get kubelet to only use the proxy when calling out to https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?

Comment: Zone not specified in configuration file. I think it requires availability zones in configuration file

Comment: @MohanShanmugam Thanks! Do you know in which config I should specify the zone?

Comment: Not sure but tell me do you follow above link https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray if yes it's an memory issue. We get same error and solved after follow the link https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/issues/974. Check it whether it help you.